# But is this a valid method to evaluate $\displaystyle\int e^{-1/x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

---

So I was bored, and decided to try and evaluate$$\int e^{-1/x^2}dx$$in as many ways as I could. After a while, I came up with this method for my first method, but I'm unsure if it's correct:

Using IBP, we get

|  | D | I |
| --- | --- | --- |
| + | $e^{-1/x^2}$ | $1$ |
| - | $2x^{-3}e^{-1/x^2}$ | $x$ |

So we get from<sup>[1]</sup>$$\text R1\text C1\cdot\text R2\text C2-\int\text R2\text C1\cdot\text R2\text C2\,dx=xe^{-1/x^2}-2\int\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}dx\because IBP$$

So now we let our integral now be$$I=xe^{-1/x^2}+I_1,I_1=-2\int\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}dx\overset{u=1/x,du=(-1/x^2)dx}=-2\int\dfrac{e^{-u^2}}{\require{cancel}\cancel{x^2}}\cancel{-x^2}du$$So now our integral is just$$I_1=2\int e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt\pi\operatorname{erf}(u)+c$$so we can *add* this to $xe^{-1/x^2}$ to get that our antiderivative is in simplest form$$I=\int e^{-1/x^2}dx=xe^{-1/x^2}+\sqrt\pi\operatorname{erf}(1/x)+c$$

---

### My question

---

Did I evaluate this correctly, or is there another, more simple way to evaluate $\displaystyle\int e^{-1/x^2}dx$?

---

##### Notes

---

<sup>[1]</sup>If anyone is confused about the $\text RX_{\text{#}_1}\text CX_{\text{#}_2}\cdot\cdots$ stuff, what I'm basically trying to say here is that what is in row X column Y is being multiplied by row Z column A or something like that for IBP

Comment: This is fine to me. Just clarify notations please

Comment: Your answer is correct, as you could find from wolfram alpha.  Another way to check your answer, is to differentiate it, and see if you recover your integrand.